# Magento calculates the grandtotal twice after calling collectTotals() in Ajax

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to apply Shipping Amount after Discounts in Magento checkout

I'm using UPS free shipping  by price, so if you total after discount is under the minimum amount for free shipping it will not grant you free shipping.

Magento calculate free shipping before discount so I calculated on my local ups.php file the correct amount after discount and applied it to the code:

```
$coupon_code=Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getCouponCode();
         Mage::getSingleton("checkout/session")->setData("coupon_code",$coupon_code);
         Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->setCouponCode($coupon_code)->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false)->collectTotals();
         //Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->setCouponCode($coupon_code)->collectTotals()->save();
         $totals =Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getTotals(); //Total object
         $subtotal = $totals["subtotal"]->getValue(); //Subtotal value

        if(isset($totals['discount']) && $totals['discount']->getValue()) {
            $discount = $totals['discount']->getValue(); //Discount value if applied
        } else {
            $discount = '';
        }       
    $r->setValue($request->getPackageValueWithDiscount( ) - $giftCardPrice);
    if($discount!='')  $r->setValueWithDiscount($subtotal-abs($discount));  
    else $r->setValueWithDiscount($request->getPackageValueWithDiscount( )- $giftCardPrice);
```

This works my problem now that in every Ajax call for shipping Magento calculates the grandtotal of the cart twice

What can I do?

Comment: What version of Magento are you on?

Comment: Using Magento Enterprise 1.9 $r is  $r = new Varien_Object(); which is applied in $this->_rawRequest = $r; by the end of collect rates